# I am having trouble making my program output correctly

Tags: c++, c++11

I am just having issues with this program big time. I have been working on it for 5 days and still no cigar. What's going on is I am trying to do the juggler sequence and I have the calculations correct, the issue I am now having is every time I do the calculations the same number keeps printing and I am having trouble making it output all the numbers on 1 line. If anyone can help that'll be great. Thank you!

This is how the output SHOULD look like but I can't get it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYl7T.jpg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;


/*
 * 
 */
int main(){

    long user_int = 0;
    long end_int = 0;
    long counter = 0;
    long int_per_line = 0;
    long user_ans = 0;

    cout << "Enter two separate numbers, check from low to high " << endl;
    cout << "Input 1st integer: ";
    cin >> user_int;
    cout << "Input 2nd integer: ";
    cin >> end_int;

    counter = user_int - 1;


    long end_start = end_int - user_int;


    cout << "Do you want to see each sequence (1=yes/0=no):  ";
    cin >> user_ans;


    while(user_ans == 1){
        for(long i = 0; i <= end_start; i++){

            if(user_int % 2 == 0){
                user_int = pow(user_int, 0.5);
                user_int = floor(user_int);
            }

            else{
                user_int = pow(user_int, 1.5);
                user_int = floor(user_int);
            }



        }


    }
    while (long i=0 <= end_start){
        counter = counter + 1;
            if(user_int != 1)
                cout << "Juggler sequence of " << counter << " is:" << user_int << endl;
    i = i + 1;
    }

    cout << "Do you want to see each sequence (1=yes/0=no):  ";
    cin >> user_ans;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're trying to get too many things working at once. Start small and simple, build up slowly, test at every step.

Comment: Is there any link you can show me to teach me how to approach a problem in a code? Thanks Beta

Comment: Move your `"Juggler sequence of "` outside the for loop and then print each `user_int` after it's calculated.  `endl` creates a new line.  If you don't want new lines don't use it there.  Place the `endl` after the for loop has finished printing the numbers.  Your second while loop is causing your problems.

Comment: Many turn up in a Google search; I don't know of any that I think hits the nail on the head. There are several things you can do, and the choice depends on circumstances. The one you seem most in need of is **simplify**. You might want to run the code 20 times while tracking down the bug, and who wants to type all those numbers? So find the parameters that will give the *simplest* run that produces the error, then hard-code those values. If you see the code is doing multiple things, separate them and test them; if a part isn't working, throw everything else away and focus on that part.

Comment: So Matt, do you suggest I completely get rid of my 2nd while loop since it's the cause of my problem

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a clear understanding of your code. I already gave your the pseudo code, but you are still not clear as far as I can tell.

Comment: Trust me I really want to solve this myself without anybody giving me the answer really bad. It feels rewarding after you solve it. Thanks Xiaotian for the help

Comment: @Giorgio To be honest, I looked at your code again, it seems worse than before...

Answer (score 1):

When the code enters into while first time, it will print something and `end_int` will become `end_start - 1` finally. Then it will never enter into while in the next for loop.

By the way, `return 0;` is also in the wrong place.

Some suggestions:

Write  a function called `void PrintJugglerSeq(int num)` which will print a juggle sequence for an input `num`.

Organize your code as following:

```
while (true) {
    read user input
    if no break;
    read two numbers (low and high)
    iterate counter from low to high {
        call PrintJugglerSeq(counter)
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you Xiaotian, but is there any possible way to do it without writing a function?

Comment: Of course you can write this without a function. My intent is to make your code clear and organized. The problem of your code is that the logic of your code is in disorder. if you don't want use function. Just put the implementation of your PrintJugglerSeq at where it's called.

Comment: Can you specify what's wrong with my logic? I'm not understanding what needs to be changed because I've gone through it a bunch of times.  I'm not understanding why it won't loop again because I keep getting stuck at 3 as my output. Shouldn't it keep looping around the "for" loop

Comment: it keep looping around "for" loop, but in the for loop, it only enter the while in the for loop for the first time. all the output is from this very first time.

Comment: And in the `while`, you keep printing the same user_int.

Comment: @Giorgio: Even if your instructor insists that you produce a solution without a function (other than `main()`), nothing prevents you from writing functions *as a way to find the bug*. You can reincorporate the functions back into `main()` later if need be.

Comment: Oh wow I got it kind of working. If you all want to take a look at it now, the only problem is it isn't outputting correct but every time I click "1" I'm getting the right calculation now

Comment: I replaced it with the variable "i"

Comment: @Giorgio, you are still printing the same `user_int` in the while

Comment: @XiaotianPei Shouldn't I be though? user_int is where I get my calculation from the for loop that I need to print?

Comment: Do you suggest I make a different variable to print the outputs?

Comment: The purpose of while is to print the sequence, not to print `user_int` for several times.

Comment: @Giorgio  Can you please indent your code, I already correct your indention. However, after your changed you code, it is wrong again.